# Extjs component handlers

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to get component handler in Ext Js? 
what are the different ways to get them like
this.lookupReference('ref-name-of-class')

```
this.lookupReferenceholder('class-name')

this.findParentByType('name-of-xtype')

Ext.ComponentQuery.query('alias-or-id')

Ext.getCmp()

this.up()......

this.down().....
```

Can anyone list all of them?

Comment: What is the point?

Comment: I want to know all the good practices to get the component.

Comment: I can think of at least 5 more off the top of my head, there are probably more. Seems kind of pointless to list all the alternatives.

Comment: With so many possibilities, a good practice is to use the same small subset everywhere. Also, I would omit the `id` and therefore `getCmp` whenever possible. `Ext.ComponentQuery.query`, `up`, `down`, `nextSibling` and `previousSibling` have covered 99% of use cases for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Gloabal IDs and Ext.getCmp() is a bad practise. It's slow and colliding global IDs will break everything.
- container.getComponent() is also a bad idea. If nesting changes, everything will break.
- parentComponent.query() should be used when you want to get multiple child components which are relatively close to the parent. If you want to get a single component, you should use down() method instead. There won't be a big performance hit if the child component you are searching is pretty close to the starting node.
- lookupReference() or just lookup() is recommended right now but it will only work within single view or viewController class.

Comment: Your assertion that `getCmp` is slow is just wrong. It looks it up in a map, it's an O(1) operation.

Comment: Please check this forum https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?311738-Best-way-to-get-reference-to-a-nested-component

Comment: I worked at Sencha for 8 years on the frameworks team. Look at the source code. Also, nice to see you just copied the forum post without attribution word for word.

Comment: Ok, you please explain me about "ref" in controllers.

Comment: I took it from sencha forum. As your team has suggested this best answer :)